# how to visualize sold Categories per each country

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-visualization

Hey im currently learning Pandas with some tutorials and im stuck now in this situation:

i have this dataset :

[Columns of the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4s1Q.png)

i want to visualize the sum of each categorie sold in a country for example :

categorie"pizza" was sold "x" times in country "y"

what i did so far is `df_clean["PRODUCTLINE"].value_counts().plot(kind="pie", figsize=(10,10))` which plots me the frequency of each Producline in the dataset

how can i visualize this in a graph?

Comment: DO NOT use images of code. Copy the actual text from your code editor, paste it into the question, then format it as code. This helps others more easily read and test your code. You could also edit your question with the added information of your comment under the first answer.

Comment: Did you try `kind='bar'` instead of `kind='pie'`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a groupby, grouping by category and country and aggregating the sales with sum.

```
df_grouped=df_clean.groupby (["COUNTRY", "PRODUCTLINE"])["SALES"].sum ()
```

Then you can plot this object just calling the .plot() method.

I also suggest you to check some tutorial about groupby in Pandas, since it's one of the most important basic concepts.

Comment: hey i already made this but my problem is i want to see in a graph for example: in country germany were sold "x","y","z" amount of a categorie vs the other countries and their  each categories sold